# How can I handle custom heading IDs with Remark?

Tags: markdown

I'm using the following function to convert Markdown to MDX:

```js
function mdxStringify(this: Processor) {
  const compiler = (tree: Node): string => {
    const markdown = toMarkdown(tree, {
      extensions: [gfmToMarkdown(), mdxToMarkdown()],
      bullet: "-",
      emphasis: "_",
      fences: true,
      resourceLink: true,
    });
    return markdown;
  };

  Object.assign(this, { Compiler: compiler });
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when there is a custom heading id like:
`### Heading {#custom-id}`, that function adds a `\` before the curly braces, according to [this page](https://mdxjs.com/docs/troubleshooting-mdx/#problems-writing-mdx) curly braces should be scaped with that syntax but it's supposed the function should allow me to parse custom heading ids properly. I used a regex expression to replace those cases and it works well but I think there must to be a better way, maybe adding some `customHeadingId` rule to the `toMarkdown` function to allow custom heading ids.

By the way, that function comes from the `mdast-util-to-markdown` package.

Hope you can help me with that, thanks in advance.